# What are universities asking for when they demand a "financial resource statement"?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am applying for a Master program and one of the documents that I have to attach to my application is a "financial resource sworn statement". What is exactly meant by this?

Is it usually enough if I upload a document stating that I have the necessary funds to support myself during the duration of the program (explaining where those funds come from) or should I attach some kind of official document from my bank?

Comment: Have you asked the department? They are going to be your best resource as to what they want.

Comment: @StrongBad I just sent them an email, but I thought that it might be somewhat common and that was why I also asked it here.

Comment: +1 I'm also curious how widespread this is. I have a family member who ran into major trouble in answering this type of inquiry for grad school,

Comment: I lean towards a bank statement. Your own statement doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @ZYX I was thinking the same but the admissions department has just answered my email and told me that it is enough if I send a dated and signed letter explaining how I plan to support myself. I'll leave the question open in case someone has a good answer which could be applied in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the financial resource statement is to determine if/how much aid you will need to complete the program. Most of the time, the most important things will be:

1. Any grants/scholarships/fellowships you will use to pay for your education.
2. How much in student loans you will use, and if they have already been approved (not common, but may happen).
3. Personal resources—including family support—you will use to support yourself.

Usually, a list is all that is needed, to show that you realize the costs of attending the program, have accounted for them, or are requesting appropriate assistance from the school. You don't necessarily have to show that you have the entire cost covered, either, especially if you are requesting aid from the University, as long as you show that you know the correct amount you need. Whether it hurts you or not in the application depends very much on the policy of the school.

If a school requires something formal, they will usually have a form you have to fill out. *I would not provide any banking data, unless absolutely required.* You don't know who works in the administration office.